# How to limiting files searched by Get-ChildItem (or limiting depth of recursion)?

Tags: powershell, filter, powershell-1.0, get-childitem

## Background

There is a directory that is automatically populated with MSI files throughout the day. I plan on leveraging Task Scheduler to run the script shown below every 15 minutes. The script will search the directory and copy any new MSIs that have been created in the last 15 minutes to a network share.

Within this folder `C:\ProgramData\flx\Output\<APP-NAME>\_<TIME_STAMP>\<APP-NAME>\` there are two other folders: `Repackaged` and `MSI Package`. The `Repackaged` folder does not need to be searched as it does not contain any MSIs. Also I have found that it needs to be excluded in some way to prevent this error:

```
Get-ChildItem : The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.
At line:14 char:32
+$listofFiles=(Get-ChildItem <<<< -Recurse -Path $outputPath -Include "*.msi" -Exclude "*.Context.msi" | where {$_.LastAccessTime -gt $time.AddMinutes($minutes)})
+ CategoryInfo : ReadError: C:\ProgramData\...xcellence\Leg 1:String) [Get-ChildItem], PathTooLongException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

### Limitations

- I am stuck using Powershell v1.0
- I have no control over the directory structure of the source location

**Updated:**

- I don't know the app name or the what the time stamp will be. That is something else that is out of my control.

### Current plans

I have read about using `-Filter` and I am aware of filters that are similar to functions but I wasn't able to come up with any ideas of how to use them. My only thought at the moment would be to do something like:

```
$searchList=Get-ChildItem "all instances of the MSI Package folder"

foreach($folder in $searchList){
    $listofFiles=Get-ChildItem "search for *.msi"

    foreach($file in $listofFiles){"Logic to copy MSI from source to destination"}
}
```

However...I thought that there might be a more efficient way of doing this.

## Questions

1. How can I limit depth that Get-ChildItem searches?
2. How can I limit the Get-ChildItem search to `C:\ProgramData\flx\Output\<APP-NAME>_<TIME_STAMP>\<APP-NAME>\MSI Package`
3. How can I only search folders that have been accessed in the last 15 minutes? I don't want to waste time drilling down into folders when I know MSI has already been copied.

Any additional advice on how to make this script more efficient overall would also be greatly appreciated.

## Script

My current script can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/uqVaX0Nt). I kept getting: "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code" and gave up after the fourth time trying to reformat it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from C.B. this is my new search which eliminates the issues I was having.

- Changed `-Path` to `C:\ProgramData\flx\Output\*\*\*\*` to help limit the depth that was searched.
- Used `-Filter` instead of `-Include` and put the `-Exclude` logic into the where clause.

`Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ProgramData\flx\Output\*\*\*\* -Filter "*.msi" | where {$_.Name -notlike "*.Context.msi" -and $_.LastAccessTime -gt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-15)}`

Answer (score 1):

You can try  this

```
dir C:\ProgramData\flx\Output\*\*\*\*\* -filter *.msi
```

this search all `.msi` files at this level

```
C:\ProgramData\flx\Output\<APP-NAME>\_<TIME_STAMP>\<APP-NAME>\Repackaged or 'MSI Package' or whatever else present folder
```

without recursion, this avoid too deep folder that give you error.

Pipe the result to:

```
Where {$_.LastAccessTime -gt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-15)} #be sure no action on file is taken before the dir command
```

or

```
Where {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-15)} #some file can be re-copied maybe
```

Comment: Using `Get-ChildItem -Path C:\ProgramData\flx\Output\*\*\*\* -Filter "*.msi" | where {$_.LastAccessTime -gt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-15)}` worked but it also returns MSIs that I would like to exclude. I tried adding `-Exclude "*.Context.msi"` but that excluded everything.

Comment: @gorideyourbike I think you need to pipe the result in a where-object: `| ? { -not $_.basename -match '\.context\.msi$' } | % { ..you logic here }`

Comment: This is what I came up with: `Get-ChildItem -Path $outputPath -Filter "*.msi" |where {$_.Name -notlike "*.Context.msi" -and $_.LastAccessTime -gt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-1440)}`. Looks like your suggestion would also work.

Comment: @gorideyourbike Good! Using `-match` with a regex can be a way for more complex filtering, but -notlike is good!

Answer (score 0):

You can't limit the recursion depth of Get-ChildItem except to not use `-Recurse` i.e. Get-ChildItem is either depth = 0 or N.

Set up variables for app name and timestamp e.g.:

```
$appName = "foo" 
$timestamp = Get-date -Format HHmmss
Get-ChildItem "C:\ProgramData\flx\Output\${appName}_$timestamp\$appName\MSI Package" -force -r
```

You can filter the results like so:

```
Get-ChildItem <path> -R | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-15)}
```

Comment: I'm not able to set the app name or time stamp. Both items are controlled by the software that creates the files and folder structure.

Comment: Do you know what the values are a priori?  If not you can use a regex to filter the output like so `gci c:\programdata\fls\output -r -force | Where {!$_.PSIsContainer -and ($_.FullName -match 'Output\\([^_]+)_[^\\]+\\\1\\MSI Package')}`